# Is there any drawback to using jpg instead of png for screenshots?

Tags: png, gnome-screenshot, jpeg

OS: Kubuntu 18.04 with `gnome-screenshot` installed.

I ran these commands consecutively on the same desktop screen:

```
gnome-screenshot -p -d 10 -f /home/dkb/"GS$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".png
```

and

```
gnome-screenshot -p -d 10 -f /home/dkb/"GS$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".jpg
```

The difference in file size of the images is remarkable (to me):

```
dkb@kububb:~$ ll *.*g
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dkb dkb 703840 May 14 10:38 GS20180514103807.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dkb dkb  68749 May 14 10:38 GS20180514103820.jpg
dkb@kububb:~$
```

Yet, the two images appear to be indistinguishable to me:

Saving as `.png`

[image: Saved as .png]

Saving as `.jpg`

[image: Saved as .jpg]

Hence my question: why shouldn't I routinely save my screenshots in `.jpg` format as opposed to the `.png` which is usually the default?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336522/png-vs-gif-vs-jpeg-vs-svg-when-best-to-use

Comment: The JPEG image in your question features visual artefacts easily noticeable with the naked eye that the PNG image doesn't contain. It becomes apparent when you open them both in separate tabs and switch between them via Ctrl+Tab.

Comment: @DavidFoerster In a fit of shear old-agedness, *I* am unable to distinguish between these pictures!

Comment: @CharlesGreen: Take a close look at the edges. If you're unsure you can “subtract” the images’ pixels from each other (e. g. with GIMP) to see only the difference between them. (Identical images would result in a completely black differential image.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PNG reproduces the original image exactly.  JPEG reduces quality it in a way that, theoretically, you shouldn't notice in normal conditions (such as, when not zooming in).

PNG is usually recommended for screenshots because it still compresses fairly well unless the screenshot contains photographic or complex imagery.  JPEG can be used if you are concerned about file size.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of some other tool.